Has the scroll from Jeremiah 51:59-64 which was tied to the stone and thrown into the middle of the Euphrates been found?
In Jeremiah 51:59-64 KJV, he instructed Serayah son of Neriyah, son of Mahseyah to read what is written once he arrived in Babylon, give a command in that Word from Yahuah, tie to a stone and throw it in the middle of the Euphrates.

Is there Scripture that records this being done by Saraiah?
Has the scroll been recovered?

Jeremiah 51 is Jeremiah 28 in the Septuagint (LXX) but the verses are the same, which is another story. Jeremiah's name may also have alternate spelling. It's been noted as "Jeremy" in the KJV Apocrypha where Baruch with the epistle to Jeremy is listed, "Jeremias" in the LXX and originally in Hebrew, it's Yirmeyahu.

What is the relevance to the question of the various spellings of "Jeremiah" in the last paragraph?

Thanks for the question Ray. If you're using a digital resource, it's helpful to know the spelling of the name you're looking for as it makes searching efficient. You'll notice that I spelled Serayah two different ways as it's found also.


Is there Scripture that records this being done by Saraiah?

No. This is the only mention of this instruction.

Has the scroll been recovered?

No, not as far as we know.

Jeremiah writings were from 627 to about 586 B.C.

Jeremiah, often called the “weeping prophet” because of his sorrow over the persistent message of God’s judgment, prophesied to the nation of Judah from the reign of King Josiah in 627 B.C. until sometime after the destruction of Jerusalem in 586. He dictated his prophecies to a scribe named Baruch (36:4, 32).
--
The Holy Bible: English Standard Version (Jer. notes). (2016). Crossway Bibles.

Parchment was invented in the 6th century B.C. but probably not readily available for Jeremiah. Parchment was more commonly available after the Seleucids and Ptolemies competed over the size of their libraries in the latter end of the 4th century B.C. because the Ptolemies controlled the papyrus in Egypt.  So, the scroll was most likely papyrus and would be short lived sunk to the bottom of a river. Even parchment would not last much longer under water. The only material that would have survived would be a gold scroll, which is highly unlikely that he used.

this article indicates that animals skins were used in the 6th c bce

@ Thank you, Dan.

This message will self-destruct?
I didn't take this to be a question about archaeology. The Euphrates is passing ~1,000 cubic metres of water per second and there have been ~80,000,000,000 seconds since the time of Jeremiah.
This is more a question of poetic form.

Jeremiah 51:63-64
וְהָיָה֙ כְּכַלֹּ֣תְךָ֔ לִקְרֹ֖א אֶת־הַסֵּ֣פֶר הַזֶּ֑ה תִּקְשֹׁ֤ר
עָלָיו֙ אֶ֔בֶן וְהִשְׁלַכְתֹּ֖ו אֶל־תֹּ֥וךְ פְּרָֽת׃
וְאָמַרְתָּ֗ כָּ֠כָה תִּשְׁקַ֨ע בָּבֶ֤ל וְלֹֽא־תָקוּם֙ מִפְּנֵ֣י
הָרָעָ֗ה אֲשֶׁ֧ר אָנֹכִ֛י מֵבִ֥יא עָלֶ֖יהָ וְיָעֵ֑פוּ עַד־הֵ֖נָּה
דִּבְרֵ֥י יִרְמְיָֽהוּ׃ ס
καὶ ἔσται ὅταν παύσῃ τοῦ ἀναγινώσκειν τὸ βιβλίον τοῦτο, καὶ ἐπιδήσεις
ἐπ’ αὐτὸ λίθον καὶ ῥίψεις αὐτὸ εἰς μέσον τοῦ Εὐφράτου
καὶ ἐρεῖς· οὕτως καταδύσεται Βαβυλὼν καὶ οὐ μὴ ἀναστῇ ἀπὸ προσώπου τῶν
κακῶν, ὧν ἐγὼ ἐπάγω ἐπ’ αὐτήν.
[63] When you finish reading this book, tie a stone to it and cast it
into the midst of the Euphrates, [64] and say, ‘Thus shall Babylon sink, to
rise no more, because of the disaster that I am bringing upon her, and
they shall become exhausted.

The referent of הַזֶּ֑ה='this' has been explained in verse 60. It's not the whole book of Jeremiah but substantially everything in Chapter 51.
But it's still strange to suppose he wrote the whole thing out again.
The section 59-60 almost looks like an explanation for "how do we still have the book of Jeremiah if it was supposed to be thrown in the water?" So I think we should consider if there are also poetic reasons for throwing the prophecy in the water.
In the Ancient Hebrew, there is a textual variant in the Aleppo Codex of 51:64 with an extra סד at the start and a פ at the end - which might indicate a textual comment. We might then need to look at וְאָמַרְתָּ֗="and say". Usually this word is the introductory formula for when God sends a prophet with a message. It's perhaps unusual that it's not said to someone.

Some comparable usages at line-starts:
Gen 32:18, Exo 4:22; Exo 7:16; Num 18:30; Num 28:3; Deu 6:21; Deu 8:17; Deu 26:13; 1Ki 22:27; 1Ch 17:4; Job 22:13; Pro 5:12; Isa 7:4; Isa 12:1; Isa 49:21; Jer 7:28; Jer 8:4; Jer 11:3; Jer 13:12; Jer 13:13; Jer 14:17; Jer 16:11; Jer 17:20; Jer 19:3; Jer 19:11; Jer 22:2;   Jer 25:27; Jer 26:4; Jer 38:26; Jer 43:10;  Jer 51:62; Jer 51:64; Eze 6:3; Eze 12:19; Eze 13:18; Eze 16:3; Eze 17:3; Eze 19:2; Eze 20:5; Eze 20:47; Eze 21:3; Eze 22:3; Eze 25:3; Eze 27:3; Eze 28:22; Eze 35:3; Eze 38:3; Eze 38:11; Eze 44:6; Zec 1:3 ; Zec 6:12
[Total: 51, of which 17 are in Jeremiah]

I'm an amateur in Ancient Hebrew, but I think I'm right in saying that in the book of Jeremiah, where וְאָמַרְתָּ֗=wə’āmartā='and say' appears at the start of a verse, it is always followed by אֲלֵיהֶם֙=alehem='to them', except in Jeremiah 19:3 where the prophecy is proclaimed to the desert, and here at Jeremiah 51:62-64 where it goes in the drink.
If the proclamation to the desert and the proclamation to the river are a framing device (or even chiastic, 19 is about halfway), then there's less reason for Saraiah or ourselves to take the instruction literally.

Jeremiah 19:3
וְאָֽמַרְתָּ֙ שִׁמְע֣וּ דְבַר־יְהוָ֔ה מַלְכֵ֣י יְהוּדָ֔ה וְיֹשְׁבֵ֖י יְרֽוּשָׁלִָ֑ם כֹּֽה־אָמַר֩ יְהוָ֨ה צְבָאֹ֜ות אֱלֹהֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵ֗ל הִנְנִ֨י מֵבִ֤יא רָעָה֙ עַל־הַמָּקֹ֣ום הַזֶּ֔ה אֲשֶׁ֥ר כָּל־שֹׁמְעָ֖הּ תִּצַּ֥לְנָה אָזְנָֽיו׃
καὶ ἐρεῖς αὐτοῖς Ἀκούσατε τὸν λόγον Κυρίου, βασιλεῖς Ἰούδα καὶ ἄνδρες Ἰούδα καὶ οἱ κατοικοῦντες Ἰερουσαλὴμ καὶ οἱ εἰσπορευόμενοι ἐν ταῖς πύλαις ταύταις Τάδε λέγει Κύριος ὁ θεὸς Ἰσραήλ Ἰδοὺ ἐγὼ ἐπάγω ἐπὶ τὸν τόπον τοῦτον κακὰ ὥστε παντὸς ἀκούοντος αὐτὰ ἠχήσει τὰ ὦτα αὐτοῦ
You shall say, ‘Hear the word of the LORD, O kings of Judah and inhabitants of Jerusalem. Thus says the LORD of hosts, the God of Israel: Behold, I am bringing such disaster upon this place that the ears of everyone who hears of it will tingle.

[LXX supplies 'to them'=αὐτοῖς but perhaps it shouldn't have]


Jeremiah 19:10-11
וְשָׁבַרְתָּ֖ הַבַּקְבֻּ֑ק לְעֵינֵי֙ הָֽאֲנָשִׁ֔ים הַהֹלְכִ֖ים אֹותָֽךְ[10]׃
[11] וְאָמַרְתָּ֙ אֲלֵיהֶ֜ם כֹּה־אָמַ֣ר ׀ יְהוָ֣ה צְבָאֹ֗ות כָּ֣כָה אֶשְׁבֹּ֞ר אֶת־הָעָ֤ם הַזֶּה֙ וְאֶת־הָעִ֣יר הַזֹּ֔את כַּאֲשֶׁ֤ר יִשְׁבֹּר֙ אֶת־כְּלִ֣י הַיֹּוצֵ֔ר אֲשֶׁ֛ר לֹֽא־יוּכַ֥ל לְהֵרָפֵ֖ה עֹ֑וד וּבְתֹ֣פֶת יִקְבְּר֔וּ מֵאֵ֥ין מָקֹ֖ום לִקְבֹּֽור׃
[10]καὶ συντρίψεις τὸν βῖκον κατ’ ὀφθαλμοὺς τῶν ἀνδρῶν τῶν ἐκπορευομένων μετά σοῦ
[11]καὶ ἐρεῖς· τάδε λέγει Κύριος· οὕτως συντρίψω τὸν λαὸν τοῦτον, καὶ τὴν πόλιν ταύτην, καθὼς συντρίβεται ἄγγος ὀστράκινον, ὃν οὐ δυνήσεται ἰαθῆναι ἔτι.
[10] “Then you shall break the flask in the sight of the men who go with you, [11]and shall say to them, ‘Thus says the LORD of hosts: So will I break this people and this city, as one breaks a potter’s vessel, so that it can never be mended. Men shall bury in Topheth because there will be no place else to bury.

The proclamation to the desert is about Judah, whereas the proclamation to the river is about Babylon. That gives a contrast with several potential layers, and which seems strong enough to be climactic.
The pot being broken is explained at Jeremiah 19:11 - "I will break this people and this city as one breaks a potter's vessel: so that it can never be mended."
And 52:64 must be taken as the corresponding/balancing explanation. "Thus shall Babylon sink, to rise no more, because of the disaster that I am bringing upon her, and they shall become exhausted."

The scroll isn't supposed to be found again.
Like the pot isn't supposed to be superglued back together. Although 19th-Century archaeologists be like: "is this the pot from Jeremiah!" "No? Well maybe this one!"
And there's a very damaging current in bible interpretation - to require the pot in Jeremiah 19 and the scroll in Jeremiah 51 to have been a literal pot and a literal scroll at any point. For the sake of briefly projecting piety, that distracts from both the symbolic contrast and the attention that must be paid to the text to notice it.
God's authority over Judah and Babylon is the original authority over the earth and the waters, is the authority over the small state and the empire, is the authority over the prophet's medium and the persistence-of-the-medium. This is perhaps a very similar sentiment to Matthew 34:25 "Heaven and earth will pass away, but my words will never pass away."
It's like when Catullus says a woman's words can be written in the breeze, or Horace's monument more lasting than bronze. We don't think less of them for not standing outside on a windy day with a licked finger, or not carrying welding equipment into the library.

The literalists on this site know who I am and downvote me for ideological hygiene. What they can't tolerate about deconstructionism is that we hold meaning is created in the reader's mind not the writer's. A regime that prohibits readers from interpreting is really prohibiting reading. Look at the regimes in our time who have books and prohibit interpretation: of course they don't read the books, they posture and parade with them. They can downvote me but make sure you ignore their diktats.

"we hold meaning is created in the reader's mind not the writer's." — But the very purpose of this site is to determine what was in the writer's mind; anything else is inappropriate here. ¶　"A regime that prohibits readers from interpreting is really prohibiting reading." — No, it is trying to maintain order within the site. Chaos has its uses, but not here.

"Biblical Hermeneutics is a question and answer site for understanding Biblical text (exegesis) using rules of interpretation (hermeneutics). We welcome Jewish, Christian, Atheist, and other viewpoints, as long as they take seriously the process of understanding Biblical texts." In the writer's mind there is only (i) what they put on the page (ii) what they didn't. Nobody cares about ii. A dead writer can't explain i to us because they're dead, and a living one can't explain i unless they stop being the writer and instead become the reader. Write=to read culture ; Read=to write exegesis.
